# I want the point line in highcharts to start with 0 ,Its position exceeds 0

Tags: highcharts

```
 chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    title: {
      text: undefined,
      style: {
        fontSize: '32px',
        fontFamily: 'Prompt',
        fontWeight: '500'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [],
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      
    },
    yAxis: [
      {
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        showEmpty: false
      }
    ],
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'left',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#636363',
        weight: '100',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    },
    colors: ['#0084FE'],
    series: []
  };
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jEJCI-MB8tqdNQLdFnubUjO4UIRq1vO9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour defaults for the `category` type xAxis.

- Set `series.pointPlacement: on` to prevent it

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lf4a6b3q/

- In case you don't pass any categories to your chart, just remove `xAxis.categories` option and set `tickWidth: 0` to achieve the same result

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a03xt5sh/

**API References**:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointPlacement
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement